# Why does the Eclipse Java compiler complain about an unchecked cast for inner derived types?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-warnings

Consider the following generic class `Base<ID>` with a non-static inner class.

```
public class Base<ID> {
  ID id;

  public Base(ID id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public ID getId() {
    return id;
  }

  protected class BaseInner {
    String text = "Inner";
  }

  protected void method(BaseInner o) {
    o.text = "Foo";
  }
}
```

The method `Base.method` takes an argument of type `BaseInner`. Now consider the following derived classes.

```
public class Sub<ID> extends Base<ID> {
  public Sub(ID id) {
    super(id);
  }

  @Override
  protected void method(BaseInner o) {

    if (o instanceof Sub.SubInner) {
      SubInner sub = (SubInner) o; // Why does this cast emit an "unchecked cast" warning

      sub.text = "Bar";
      sub.value = 1337;
    }
  }

  protected class SubInner extends BaseInner {
    Number value = 42;
  }
}
```

The class `Sub` derives from `Base` and the inner class `SubInner` derives from the inner class `BaseInner`. The generic type parameter `ID` of `Sub`is passed as type argument to the base class `Base`.

**My question:** Why does the compiler complain about the cast from `BaseInner` to `SubInner` in the overriding `method` of `Sub`?

To understand the warning I tried to construct a use case in which the `method` of a `Sub<A>` is called with some `Sub<B>.SubInner` that justifies the warning. But anything I can think of (including `? extends` and `? super`) emits a compiler error on the method call, if the types are not compatible.

So I guess there is no reason to for the warning of an unchecked cast in the `method`. Did I miss something?

As the method override happens within the `Sub<ID>` implementation, the compiler is able to deduct the generic type of `SubInner` to `Sub<ID>.SubInner`. So question this is **not** a duplicate!

The Eclipse compiler warning is

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Base<ID>.BaseInner to Sub<ID>.SubInner

The waring doesn't change neither if I use `Base<ID>.BaseInner` as method parameter nor if I use `Sub<ID>.SubInner` in the cast expression.

Comment: Just a guess, but since you're using `o instanceof Sub.SubInner` in the if statement shouldn't you also be using `Sub.SubInner` in the following statement?

Comment: I already tried that and also using `Sub<ID>.SubInner` in the cast, but it always produces the same warning.

Comment: What compiler are you using? I don't get any warnings with javac 8.

Comment: OK I guess it is an Eclipse compiler issue! If Javac does not complain at all! I can cast to `SubInner` as expected! (no extra qualification of the generic type like `Sub<ID>.SubInner`necessary)

Comment: @Andy Tuner: this is NOT a duplicate. The javac compiler does not emit any waring for my code! Please reopen the question, so we can add a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seams to be an Eclipse compiler issue.

The Oracle compiler (`javac`) does not omit any warnings here.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, unchecked cast means you are casting from an unqualified type to a generic type.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet();
```

This line will produce an unchecked assignment warning too.

This warning occurs because there is no way for the compiler to deduct if the cast is safe on the compile time.

SubInner instance has a reference to Sub instance. You are casting from Base.BaseInner, so you are also casting from Base to Sub< ID >. Therefore, you are having this warning.

**Edit**

Solution is to use generic parameter.

```
public class Base<ID> {
    ID id;

    public Base(ID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected class BaseInner {
        String text = "Inner";
    }

    protected void method(Base<ID>.BaseInner o) {
        o.text = "Foo";
    }
}


public class Sub<ID> extends Base<ID> {
    public Sub(ID id) {
        super(id);
    }

    @Override
    protected void method(Base<ID>.BaseInner o) {
        SubInner sub = (SubInner) o; 
        sub.text = "Bar";
        sub.value = 1337;
    }

    protected class SubInner extends BaseInner {
        Number value = 42;
    }
}
```

Comment: "This line will produce an unchecked cast warning too." No, it will produce a raw types warning. There's no cast there.

Comment: I already tried to add the generic type arguments to SubInner and to the method with no success.

Comment: Adding SubInner the type argument won't solve the problem since SubInner has a reference to a Sub object, which is generic. Therefore, Base class you are casting from should be generic too. Otherwise, you will be casting from unqualified type to a generic type.